# Absolute URL in template returns localhost in email templates

Tags: php, twig, symfony-2.8

I'm using `absolute_url` function defined [here](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/twig_reference.html#url) in my twig email template that is triggered via symfony command but the path only returns `localhost/route` instead of the complete URL `http://abc.local/route`.

```
<a href="{{ absolute_url('downloads') }}">download</a>
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 4):

**Solution with Symfony-5.4**

Generating URLs in commands works the same as generating URLs in services. The only difference is that commands are not executed in the HTTP context. Therefore, if you generate absolute URLs, you'll get `http://localhost/` as the host name instead of your real host name.

The solution is to configure the `default_uri` option to define the "request context" used by commands when they generate URLs:
On *config/packages/routing.yaml* add the URL of the real host.

```
# config/packages/routing.yaml    
framework:
    router:
        # ...
        default_uri: 'https://example.org/my/path/'
```

> The default_uri option was introduced in Symfony 5.1.

For reference please see the official documentation.
https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/routing.html#generating-urls-in-commands

Comment: another option is to change the messenger configuration of `Symfony\Component\Mailer\Messenger\SendEmailMessage` from `async` to `sync` (make sure the `sync transport` isn't commented). This makes it send the emails immediatly rather tham queueing them to be consumed with a cron - that way it still has the HTTP context and the url comes out correctly